# Why is my JS script not running even though I call it correctly in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript

I'm super new to JS and I know it might be a stupid question but I want to know why this happens. Basically I wrote some JS and reloaded the website and it worked. But then I changed the code to do something else and then the whole JS code just wouldn't execute. Any idea why?

I've tried troubleshooting this on YouTube and I couldn't find any video showing exactly what I am experiencing. Again I know it might be something basic and stupid that I'm missing but I want to know what exactly I did wrong.

```
var name;
var valid = false;
var age;

function enterName() {
  name = prompt("Hello, what is your name?");
  if (name !== "") {
    alert(`Hi ${name}`);
    getAge();
  } else {
    alert("You have not entered a name and so I don't know who your are");
  }
}
enterName();

function getAge() {
  age = 2019 - prompt("In which year were you born?");
  while (valid === false) {
    if (age === "") {
      alert("You have not entered an age and so I don't know how old you are");
      valid = false;
    } else {
      valid = true;
    }// end else
  } // end while

  if (valid === true) {
    if (age >= 18) {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and qualify for a drivers license`);
    }else {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and do not qualify for a drivers license`);
    }// end else
  } // end if valid == true
}// end function
```

I want it to call the enterName function to receive the name from the user and then call the getAge function to work out the age of the user for any future purpose (in this case determining if the user is eligible for a drivers license)
I expect it to call the functions as written but when I refresh the page, nothing happens

My HTML is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script src="/Users/neillfinn/Desktop/Website/js/main.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Open your console (press F12 in most browsers) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: `if (age === "")` won't ever be `true`

Comment: you have a problem in your last template string. you have the emoji outside the string

Comment: Open the browser console and check if it's showing any error. Also make sure that the website cache is disabled when you are testing.

Answer (score 2):

You kept string outside quotes. An issue in below line

```
 alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and do not qualify for a drivers license`);
```

```js
var name;
var valid = false;
var age;

function enterName() {
  name = prompt("Hello, what is your name?");
  if (name !== "") {
    alert(`Hi ${name}`);
    getAge();
  } else {
    alert("You have not entered a name and so I don't know who your are");
  }
}
enterName();

function getAge() {
  age = 2019 - prompt("In which year were you born?");
  while (valid === false) {
    if (age === "") {
      alert("You have not entered an age and so I don't know how old you are");
      valid = false;
    } else {
      valid = true;
    }// end else
  } // end while
  
  if (valid === true) {
    if (age >= 18) {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and qualify for a drivers license`);
    }else {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and do not qualify for a drivers license `);
    }// end else
  } // end if valid == true
}// end function
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. We have a close reason for that. See [answer].

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Hereafter will follow it. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

In the line `` alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and do not qualify for a drivers license`); ``, you have the ending quotation mark before the emoji, and it needs to be after. Fixing that appears to make it work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var name;
var valid = false;
var age;

function enterName() {
  name = prompt("Hello, what is your name?");
  if (name !== "") {
    alert(`Hi ${name}`);
    getAge();
  } else {
    alert("You have not entered a name and so I don't know who your are");
  }
}
enterName();

function getAge() {
  age = 2019 - prompt("In which year were you born?");
  while (valid === false) {
    if (age === "") {
      alert("You have not entered an age and so I don't know how old you are");
      valid = false;
    } else {
      valid = true;
    }// end else
  } // end while

  if (valid === true) {
    if (age >= 18) {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and qualify for a drivers license`);
    }else {
      alert(`${name} you are ${age} years old and do not qualify for a drivers license`);
    }// end else
  } // end if valid == true
}// end function
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. We have a close reason for that. See [answer].